# Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: Error in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I created a short program to experiment with removing an element from an array by its value, rather than by index. I then want to print the updated list having removed this element.

However, I'm getting an error:
'Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'list' is a 'let' constant'.
Why is `list` a constant value? Not sure if this is relevant, but I declared the array `quarantineStuff` as a variable. Why would `list` take a constant by default?

```
var quarantineStuff: [String] = ["zero to one book", "proper twelve whiskey", "coffee", "tonic water", "toilet roll", "broken electronics"]

func removeItemsICantTakeWithMe(list: [String]) -> [String] {
    if let index = list.firstIndex(of: "toilet roll") {
        list.remove(at: index)
    }
    return list
}

let renewedList = removeItemsICantTakeWithMe(list: quarantineStuff)
print(renewedList)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var quarantineStuff: [String] = ["zero to one book", "proper twelve whiskey", 
"coffee", "tonic water", "toilet roll", "broken electronics"]

func removeItemsICantTakeWithMe(list: [String]) -> [String] {
    var aList = list // method object is immutable so we have to make a mutable object         

    if let index = aList.firstIndex(of: "toilet roll") {
        aList.remove(at: index)
    }
    return aList
}

let renewedList = removeItemsICantTakeWithMe(list: quarantineStuff)
print(renewedList)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. Can you explain why 'list' is a constant which is making me create a new variable to stand in?

Comment: @ArpitSingh When making a local mutable copy of a parameter, it's conventional to use the same name as the parameter, `var list = list`. It shadows it nicely, so there's no confusion between the two, and there's no need to make it arbitrarily distinct, like prefixing `a` as you did

Comment: @timman All non-`inout` parameters are immutable. You need to make a mutable local copy, if you want to do mutating operations. Alternatively, you could pass your `list` in as an `inout [String]`, but that's not usually advisable if you can avoid it, unless you have good reason to.

Comment: Let is an immutable variable, meaning that it cannot be changed, languages call this a constant. Var is a mutable variable, meaning that it can be changed.

Comment: Thanks Arpit. I do know this main diff between let and var, but just wondering why list as a given parameter is set to be a constant and hence the need to create the variable copy? @Alexander says above that 'all non-inout parameters are immutable'. What does that mean?

Comment: @timman If you don't understand my comment, you can just ask me directly :)

Comment: Sorry, @Alexander that was an indirect question! Had to just include one @ and it got muddled.

Comment: Function parameters are constants by default. Trying to change the value of a function parameter from within the body of that function results in a compile-time error. This means that you can’t change the value of a parameter by mistake. If you want a function to modify a parameter’s value, and you want those changes to persist after the function call has ended, define that parameter as an in-out parameter instead. As per Swift book

Answer (score 5):

All parameters in Swift are implicitly `let` / constants.

If you need to modify a parameter, you need to make it a `var` explicitly in your code:

```
func removeItemsICantTakeWithMe(list: [String]) -> [String] {
    var list = list // insert this line
    if let index = list.firstIndex(of: "toilet roll") {
        list.remove(at: index)
    }
    return list
}
```

Alternatively, you can use `inout` parameters to achieve a similar effect.